# CSS3 media query not working

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am using the following media queries on my website.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="web.css" media="only screen and (min-device-width : 1025px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ipad.css" media="only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px)" />
```

My intention here was to have different stylesheets for different devices. (For now I want to support only desktops and ipads).

But when I load the website on my desktop using Firefox (Version 8) or Chrome (Ver: 15.0.874.106) it downloads both the CSS files (both web.css and ipad.css).

I am not too sure what is the wrong with my code. Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 3):

for `Desktop` you have to write `min-width` instead of `min-device-with` like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="web.css" media="only screen and (min-width : 1025px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ipad.css" media="only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px)" />
```

Comment: The problem here is, on Desktop, it is downloading both the css files. I suppose it should not be downloading ipad.css on desktop and viceversa. Is my assumption wrong?

Comment: it's not download both css files because min-width refer to screen size of the page & min-device-width means it's active when it's open in a device like iphone & ipad

Comment: read this article for more http://css-tricks.com/6206-resolution-specific-stylesheets/

Answer (score 1):

IT might not work, but try changing the values down a number:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="web.css" media="only screen and (min-device-width : 1024px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ipad.css" media="only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1023px)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Browsers that support the use of media queries will download all of your stylesheets regardless of which one it needs to display unfortunately.

These queries will give you two different layout handles based on resolution, rather than device, but both stylesheets will always be downloaded.

```
media="screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px)"
media="screen and (min-width: 1025px)"
```