# Can i fake css media only screen with firefox?

Tags: css, ipad

I have a website that is giving me undue problems with ipad viewing. (if you check muy other questions and have ideas about fixing it, you'd be my hero!)

In an effort to work on this, i've tried to view my site using firefox on my pc, to see what the sizes are like when using my ipad (with the firebug add-on).

Question: in my css, I use:
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape){
...
}

this doesn't appear to be getting picked up by firefox though. For firefox, i'm using the addon here:
http://chrispederick.com/work/user-agent-switcher/

with a new type defined, called ipad, as so:
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.10
(i didn't change the other values, just the "user-agent" option. Still, other websites pick up that i'm an "ipad", so i think it works)

HOWEVER, my css files aren't getting picked up (or rather, the modified version isn't coming through). Is this likely:
a problem with firebug, and the css is being rendered
OR
a problem with the user-agent switcher, and the thing - whatever it is - that works out which css to use knows i'm on ff for pc
OR
a problem with my css switching?

cheers!

Answer (score 2):

take a look at [CSS3 media query not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079036/css3-media-query-not-working) the second answer could solve your problem

Basically the idea is to change `(min|max)-device-width` with `(min|max)-width`

from http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/

> Keep in mind this is the device width, not the current width of the browser window. On the iPhone (3G(s)), that means 480px. My fancy new MacBook Pro is going to return 1920px for the device width. But my actual browser window is only half of that at this exact moment. The device width is quite useful when dealing with mobile devices where the browser is probably 100% of the screen whenever in use, but less useful in laptop/desktop browsers.